# How do I eliminate linear dependence in a difference-in-difference model in R?

Tags: r, regression, panel-data, multicollinearity, difference-in-difference

I am using panel data to try and observe the effects of Vietnamese immigration in the California Bay Counties in the 1980s. I am using R.

I am regressing average weekly wages (adjusted for inflation) on the interaction between the percentage of Vietnamese in the county in 1980 with the dummy variable for after 1980 (when there is an observed wave of Vietnamese immigrants to the region). I am including county, year, and quarter fixed effects.

[image]

However, using the `alias()` command in R, I find that I have linear dependence between my 'post' dummy variable and the year dummies starting with '1980' (the "treatment" period).

[image]

I am not good with econometrics and coding, and I am sure the solution is quite obvious. If someone could please tell me what I am doing wrong and what I should do to correct this issue I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Welcome to CV. You have multiple versions of “time” in your model. How long is your panel?

Comment: @ThomasBilach My panel includes years 1975 to 1985, and it has quarterly values for each year.

Comment: Do you want to match the granularity in your outcome? If so, then shouldn’t you have weekly data over those years?

Comment: I got the wage data from the BLS site (from their Quarterly Census of Employment and Wages). I believe the avg_weekly_wage variable is the average weekly wage in that quarter. I do not have weekly data for any other variable. @ThomasBilach

Comment: Is the immigrant influx starting in 1980 for all treated bay area counties? Or do some experience the influx early while others experience it much later? And lastly, do any of the bay area counties receive no new arrivals over this time period?

Comment: Sorry, I have not really explained much of the background to what I am trying to get at. Essentially, in 1975, there was a big influx of refugees from Vietnam to the United States. Over the course of a couple of years, they formed enclaves in several counties in the US. Then, in 1980, and for a year or two after,  there was a large influx of Vietnamese refugees to the USA again.

Comment: Prior literature relies on the assumption that, "many newly arriving immigrants settle in enclaves established by earlier immigrants from the same source countries" (Card 2001) to argue that particular immigrant inflows are exogenous to local labor market conditions. So, I am also relying on this assumption and am looking at counties in the California Bay Area. Two counties, San Francisco and Santa Clara, had existing Vietnamese enclaves by 1980. The other 7 counties in my data do not (relatively).

Comment: So, assuming that areas with existing foreign-born enclaves can expect immigrants from the same sending country, I have two counties who receive "treatment" to the second wave of immigration. The other counties won't be spared from receiving immigrants, of course, but I am making the argument that they won't be 'treated' to the same degree. So, I am trying to create a model where the ‘treatment’ is a continuous variable: the percent of Vietnamese residents in a county. The “after” period is 1980, the period after which most Vietnamese immigrants will be settling in America.

Comment: This paper (https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/aer.20170765) uses the specification I am describing to study the effects of the end of the Bracero Program in the USA. However, they do not give many details on their data or regression to help me understand what I am doing differently that is causing me issues.

Comment: Thank you for your help up til now, by the way. I really appreciate it! @ThomasBilach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paper by Clemens and colleagues (2018) suggests they're working with multiple state-time pairs.

On page 1478 of their paper they state the following:

> "We use difference-in-differences with continuous treatment...where $y_{st}$ is the outcome in state $s$ in year, quarter, or month $t$..."

It follows from this statement that they're estimating *separate* equations using different time units. I encourage you to read the corresponding notes under their tabular results. Table 1 is a regression using *state-quarter* observations. Table 2 is a regression using *state-month* observations. They did not estimate one model. In fact, they estimated separate DiD equations using different time units.

Later, the authors state they use state and quarter-by-year (month-by-year) fixed effects. I understand how this sounds confusing, as it may suggest they estimated, concurrently, quarter *and* year fixed effects, or month *and* year fixed effects, separately. But you'd be wrong. The reason they use the term quarter-by-year (month-by-year) fixed effects is because we must assign a separate time-specific intercept for all quarters (months). Note how it shouldn't be a repeating interval. For instance, say you observe 100 U.S. counties over 10 years (i.e., 1960 – 1969) but your data is in quarterly time units. The model should include 99 (i.e., $N - 1$) county effects and 39 (i.e., $T - 1$) quarter effects. To obtain 39 unique quarter effects, we often instantiate a quarter-year variable. Now quarter 1 in 1960 is distinct from quarter 1 in 1961, hence the term quarter-by-year fixed effect.

The "time" fixed effect should be either at the month, quarter, or year level. And, if it's at a level lower than the year, it shouldn't be a repeating interval (e.g., 1 – 12 months). Rather, if you're observing counties from 1960 – 1969 at *monthly* time units, then your model should be estimating 119 (i.e., $T - 1$) *month* effects. Again, this is capturing the common shocks affecting all counties in **each month-year period**, not just in, say, September.

Now in your specific case, your model includes both year fixed effects and quarter fixed effects. If estimated in the order provided in your post, then the year effects would absorb the quarter effects. Any one year effect is a linear combination of the 4 quarter effects. To demonstrate this, the abridged data frame below shows Napa county from 1960 – 1961.

$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
county & year & quarter & y_{1960} & y_{1961} & q_1 & q_2 & q_3 & q_4 & \sum_{t = 1}^{4}q_t \\
\hline
 \text{Napa} & 1960 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 \text{Napa} & 1960 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 \text{Napa} & 1960 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 \text{Napa} & 1960 & 4 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 \text{Napa} & 1961 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 \text{Napa} & 1961 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 \text{Napa} & 1961 & 3 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 \text{Napa} & 1961 & 4 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
$$

The data frame includes a full set of year indicators (i.e., $y_{1960}$, $y_{1961}$, etc.) and a full set of quarter indicators (i.e., $q_1$, $q_2$, etc.). In the last column, I summed *across* the quarter dummies. Note how the year effect in 1960 is a linear combination of the 4 quarter effects (i.e., $y_{1960} = q_1 + q_2 + q_3 + q_4$). We can't include both in a linear equation!

I hope the redundancies are a bit more evident once we instantiate all the different time effects. In practice, R should drop the quarter effects for you without any additional work on your part. Examine your summary output and you should see `NA` values for the quarter effects. However, if you want to estimate a model using the quarterly data, then drop the year fixed effects.

I would suggest including county fixed effects, quarter fixed effects, and a continuous policy variable. The quarter fixed effects are, technically, quarter-by-year fixed effects. In the previous data frame, you'd be estimating 7 (i.e., $T - 1$) quarter effects, not 4! Instantiating a quarter-year variable is appropriate, and it will distinguish between the effect in $q_1$ in 1960 and $q_2$ in 1961.

---

***Coding suggestions:***

I have no problems with you interacting the proportion of new arrivals with a post-treatment variable. Technically, this is what the continuous policy variable represents. It should equal 0 in the pre-period before any new arrivals emerge, then take on positive values at time $t$ to reflect the proportion of immigrants settling into a treated region in 1980. If, however, different counties experience a Vietnamese influx at different times, then the `post` variable isn't well-defined and I'd recommend instantiating the interaction term manually. Let's call the new continuous treatment variable `immigration`, which is the interaction of `post` and `viet_perc` just defined in a different way. The basic structure is as follows:

```
lm(wage ~ as.factor(county_code) + as.factor(quarter_year) + immigration + control_variables, data = ...)
```

On the other hand, if `post` *is* well-defined and the interaction term is expressed inside of the model formula, then `post` will be absorbed by the quarter fixed effects. Similarly, if `viet_perc` is expressed as a simple jump in intensity and exhibits no variation over time, then it will be absorbed by the county fixed effects. In other words, the constituent terms won't show up in your output, but the interaction term will remain. The basic structure is as follows:

```
lm(wage ~ as.factor(county_code) + as.factor(quarter_year) + viet_prop * post + control_variables, data = ...) ​
```

I would need to review a subset of your data to offer further guidance. Again, it's permissible to instantiate the interaction term before feeding it into the `lm()` function. The resulting model is a two-way fixed effects equation with a continuous policy variable. In fact, the first code block should have no redundant terms.

Lastly, I would avoid using `as.factor(post)` and wrapping the multiplicative term in parentheses, though it won't affect your results. The variable `post` should be either 0 or 1. It could enter the model *as is* and requires no further modification inside of the `lm()` function.

Comment: I am embarrassed that I did not comprehend the nuance of the time fixed-effects in the Clemens paper. I created a quarter-by-year variable as you suggested, and this solved my initial problem. Thank you so much! You have done me a humongous favor!

Comment: No problem! Please consider giving it a check if it helped.